# TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U32') and format specifier ('%.18e')

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

I am using `np.savetxt` for the first time, and I am trying to save two variables (a string and a float) in a file named "trial.csv" as follows:

```
import numpy as np

RT = 2.76197329736740
key_name = 'space'

print(RT,key_name)
# Save data in a CSV file named subj_data_file
np.savetxt("trial.csv", (RT,key_name), delimiter=',', header="RTs,Key_Name")
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U32') and format specifier ('%.18e')
```

I do not understand the meaning of both `('<U32')` and `('%.18e')`. As a matter of fact, I do not understand how to use `fmt` when I have floats, integers and strings ...

It is a simplified example, but concretely, I would have the RT values (floats) in one column "RTs" and the key_name (float) values in another column "Key_Name". I will create more columns later on, and although I provided one value for RT and one value for key_name in this example, there will be more RT values in the column "RTs" as well as key names in the column "Key_Name".

Comment: `savetxt` writes a numpy array to the file, having first converted it to strings via the `fmt`.  The default `fmt` is '%.18e', with converts a number to something like '1.234e10'.  To see what it's trying to save, `print(np.array({RT, key_name))`.  Saving a mix of numbers and strings with `savetxt` isn't a trivial task.

Comment: @hpaulj it prints `{2.713, 'space'}`. Shall I then choose a different method to save a mix of data types in a CSV file?

Comment: I get `array(['2.7619732973674', 'space'], dtype='<U32')`.  It makes an array with string values,  not a mix of number and string.  Do you really have to save the label with it the number.  For a beginner, saving and loading just numbers is a lot easier than a mix of numbers and strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

names  = np.array(['NAME_1', 'NAME_2', 'NAME_3'])
floats = np.array([ 0.1234 ,  0.5678 ,  0.9123 ])

ab = np.zeros(names.size, dtype=[('key_name', 'U6'), ('RT', float)])
ab['key_name'] = names
ab['RT'] = floats

np.savetxt('trial.csv', ab, fmt="%10s , %10.3f", header="Keys_Names,RTs")
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I tried to create headers as follows: `np.savetxt('trial.csv', ab, fmt="%10s %10.3f", header="Keys_Names,RTs")` but all the values (both floats and the names) are under the same column "Keys_Names". How can I add a header and assign each other to its respective variable?

Comment: You are miost welcome, you just need to add one , between fmt.

Comment: @Kathia I edited my answer as you wanted headers aligned for columns value, if I could solve please accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the default `fmt` argument in `np.savetxt()` is `'%.18e'` which is suitable for numbers (integers/floats). If you want to save strings as well, you need to change the `fmt` argument to be `'%s'`.

Also, you need to change the `X` shape to reflect the fact that it's one row with two columns. So, you need to change `np.savetxt` to be just like so:

```
np.savetxt("trial.csv", [[RT, key_name]], fmt="%s", delimiter=',', header="RTs,Key_Name")
```

This means that everything will be saved as string. So, the value `2.761..` won't be a float. You can load this file like so:

```
np.loadtxt("trial.csv",delimiter=',', dtype=str) #notice assiging dtype to str
```

Comment: This solution gets rid of the type error, thanks. However, when I tried to load the data with `data = np.loadtxt("trial.csv",delimiter=',')` then `pprint.pprint(data.tolist())`, I get the error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'space'`. Moreover, when I open the file "trial.csv", I see that it created two columns "RTs" and "Key_Name" but both values (2.76197329736740 and 'space') are in the rows of the first column (RTs) instead of having 'space' in the column "Key_Name"

Comment: The default datatype in `np.loadtxt` is `float`, change it to `str` like so: `np.loadtxt("trial.csv",delimiter=',', dtype=str)`. Anyway, I will edit my answer to include this part.

Comment: It definitely fixes the ValueError since it converts everything to string - which can be a solution for me since I can convert back the values to float when I will process the data. However, I still have both values (2.76197329736740 and 'space') stored in a single column (RTs). Is it because of the formatting `fmt="%s"`?

Comment: No, because of the way you represent your data. I've edited my answer to use `[[RT, key_name]]` instead of `(RT, key_name)`